# Classe não encontrada. Namespace e composer psr-4

Tags: php, laravel, composer, namespace

Pessoal fiz tudo o que diz nas demais perguntas sobre o assunto, mas não resolveu o meu problema. Por isso abri uma nova pergunta.

Minha classe não está sendo encontrada.

esta é a minha estrutura:

```
project
   _app
      |-- User.php
   vendor
      |-- composer
      |-- autoload.php
   composer.json
   index.php
```

Esta é a minha classe:

```
<?php
namespace project\_app;

class User {}
```

Esta é a minha index:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";

use \project\_app\User;

$user = new User;

?>
```

Este é o composer:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
         "project\\": "_app/"
    }
}
```

Este é o erro retornado:

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'project\_app\User' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\index.php on line 18
( ! ) Error: Class 'project\_app\User' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\index.php on line 18
```

Comment: Você tem _app sobrando no namespace, ou então, deveria criar um diretório _app dentro de _app e colocar User.php lá.

Answer (score 0):

Você está referenciando "project" para pasta "_app", portanto você não precisa mais repetir esse "_app";

Ex:

```
<?php
namespace project;

class User {}
```

...

```
 <?php
 require __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";
 use project\User;
 $user = new User;
```

Após fazer isso teste novamente, caso apresnete erro atualize o autoloader do composer:

```
composer dump-autoload -o
```